# Supabase cron job

Tags: postgresql, cron, supabase, supabase-database

I have created two cron jobs:

```
SELECT cron.schedule('Every minute testcron','*/1 * * * *', $$UPDATE testcron SET number = number + 1 $$)
```

```
SELECT cron.schedule('Every minute','*/1 * * * *', $$UPDATE testcronwithdate SET Date = Date + interval '1 day'$$)
```

The first cron job 'Every minute testcron' runs every minute and increments the integer in number column with +1.
The second cron job called 'Every minute' I want to update my dates in the date column with 1 day (datatype date).

I can't get the second one to work, the days are not updated, while on the first cron job the number is incremented by one and is working.

when running:

```
select * from cron.job;
```

I can see both my schedulers.

RLS is not enabled.

Why wont the days update each minute?

Comment: 1) This `... SET Date = Date ...` is probably not a good idea. Making a field name the same as a type name is bound to cause confusion. 2) Look at the Postgres log and see what it says when the UPDATE is attempted.

Comment: Thanks alot! It looks like the naming was the issue as you pointed out, the log was not very clear.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the log said something along lines of `column "date" does not exist`?

Comment: yes, thats what it said.